# Add a new custom div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a small web application that allows users to add sticky notes to a page by clicking the add button. The following is the html that makes up a sticky note.

```
<div class="sticky_note">
    <div class="title">
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="My Title"><span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <textarea name="note" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am just a bit unsure how to add another sticky note everytime the user clicks add. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var stickyNote = $('.sticky_note')[0].outerHTML;
$('#addBtn').click(function(){
  $stickyNote = $(stickyNote);
  $stickyNote.appendTo($('.sticky_notes_container'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky_notes_container">
<div class="sticky_note">
    <div class="title">
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="My Title"><span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <textarea name="note" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<button id=addBtn>Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was wondering if you could shed any light on why the css styles for the dynamically added element are not displaying. Thanks!

Comment: create a small working example with css you are referring and then  elaborate on what problem you are facing

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an html element by pressing a button, for example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'window'; //you can assign property to your element.

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.id = 'windowhead';
div.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

this code append a div into another main container. I hope that this can be help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a new div.By using

```
document.createElement("div")
```

You can add text, classes..just look up w3school for more details..

Also i see your requirement, that clicking on button it will create a sticky note..

Element.cloneNode()

Might be helpful for you..where you make a div once with all the design and structure and use it again again..

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Comment: `document.createElement('div')`

Comment: By mistake d was captial didnt noticed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all this is inside a main container ,just keep that `var code=<div class="sticky_note">...</div>` code in a string and use

```
$("container").append(code);
```